# How to start again at the beginning of the word?

Tags: python, python-3.x

To apply a Vigenere coding, we have to shift the letters but not all by the same number. The key is this time a keyword which each letter gives us the shift to be done (taking A for a shift of 0, B for a shift of 1 ...).

Let's take an example to explain the method: Let's imagine that the keyword is "MATHS" and the word to code is "PYTHON".
To code P, I shift the number corresponding to M, i.e. 12 (because we start at 0 with A) which gives me B as coding for P.
Let's move on to Y: I shift it by the number corresponding to A, i.e. 0, so Y is the coding for Y here.
Let's go to T which is shifted by the number corresponding to T, i.e. 19, so T becomes M once shifted
And so on.

```
import string

def vigenere_cipher(msg, shift):
    encrypted = ''
    for i,j in zip(msg,shift):
        new_index = ( string.ascii_uppercase.index(i) + string.ascii_uppercase.index(j) ) % 26
        encrypted += string.ascii_uppercase[new_index]
    return encrypted
print(vigenere_cipher('PYTHON', 'MATH'))
```

If our keyword is too short we start again at the beginning of the word, i.e. N will be shifted by the number corresponding to M.

My problem right here is actually with the last part, How I can simply say that if the keyword is too short we start again at the beginning of the word ?

Because only "PYTH" part is encrypted to "BYMO" with MATH as a key but not the "ON"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue here is that you're zipping both `msg` and `shift` together, when you don't actually need to do so. You already understand the concept of using `%` to guarantee that you stay on a number smaller than your max number, so I'll modify your function to also use `%` to select which character from shift you want to use

```py
import string

def vigenere_cipher(msg, shift):
    encrypted = ''
    shift_length = len(shift)
    for i, char in enumerate(msg):
        new_index = ( string.ascii_uppercase.index(char) + string.ascii_uppercase.index(shift[i % shift_length]) ) % 26
        encrypted += string.ascii_uppercase[new_index]
    return encrypted

print(vigenere_cipher('PYTHON', 'MATH'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the line `shift = shift * (len(msg) // len(shift) + 1)` at the start of the function so `shift` is repeated until it's longer than `msg` (e.g. this line turns `MATH` into `MATHMATH`)

```py
import string

def vigenere_cipher(msg, shift):
    shift = shift * (len(msg) // len(shift) + 1)
    encrypted = ''
    for i,j in zip(msg,shift):
        new_index = (string.ascii_uppercase.index(i) + string.ascii_uppercase.index(j)) % 26
        encrypted += string.ascii_uppercase[new_index]
    return encrypted

    
print(vigenere_cipher('PYTHON', 'MATH'))
```

Output: `BYMOAN`

Comment: why I didn't think of it before...